# can you tell me why this will only sort to the value of 10?

Tags: php, sorting, mysqli

Below is a snippet of code that takes all my data from my database and sorts them and shows them, it currently sorts them by # of votes all the way up to 10 votes, it seems almost as if it is sorting only off the first number,

```
<tr bgcolor="transparent">
    <td colspan="3" class="pages"><?php echo $pages_site; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php foreach($members as $member){
    $votes  =htmlentities($member['votes']);
    $id     =htmlentities($member['id']);
    $url    =htmlentities($member['first_name']);
    $sname  =htmlentities($member['last_name']);
    $status =htmlentities($member['status']);
    $desc   =htmlentities($member['bio']);
    $banner =htmlentities($member['image_location']);
?>
<tr>
    <td class="site"></td>
    <td class="site_th"><A href="<?php echo $url ?>"><?php echo $sname ?><br><? echo $desc ?></br><a href="<?php echo $url ?>"><img src="<? echo $banner ?>" style="max-width:500px;max-height:200px";></A></td>
    <td class="vote_th">VOTES:<?php echo $votes ?><br><a href="vote.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>">VOTE!</a> </td>
</tr>
<?
    }
?></table>
```

i've tried moving votes to the top of the db and tried changing the defult value of votes to 00 rather then 0 but that makes it show 01 rather then just 1, and i would prefer avoid that if possable

Comment: echo the $members variable, and see the total amount of elements in the array, I presume there are only ten elements, hence why it only goes up to ten. Please confirm :)

Comment: '$members =$users->get_users();
public function get_users() {

  $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `votes` DESC");
  
  try{
   $query->execute();
  }catch(PDOException $e){
   die($e->getMessage());
  }

  return $query->fetchAll();

 } 
}'

Comment: did you even read my comment properly? please read it again and reply accordingly! hehe, dude I asked you to check your $members variable possibly by echoeing it so you can see how many elements there are within the array!

Comment: and when the output was Array; Array; Array; Array; Array; i decided to show you what the $members variable was. also i couldn't workout how to code wrap comments.

Comment: do print_r($members); anyway please explain your questio clearly as we are not getting anywhere. Your question seems to ask why your code only sorts to the value of 10. It does not look like you are doing any sorting out to me in that code. One reason that it only sorts to 10 is because your foreach loop only gets executed 10 times due to the members variable only having 10 elements

Comment: the foreach loop has and had little to do with the problem, it was sorting to the value of 10 because it would only see the first digit. i ended up changing the rows defult state to 000000 instead of 0 and then used printf("%01d",$votes) to show 11 instead of 000011 the problem has been solved but thankyou for trying